# Using this login secure with cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

Looking for perhaps a little input on any vulnerabilities with this login script.

step 1 - input form with username and password gets submitted

step 2 - upon verification I would insert a uniqid into DB called session

step 3 - In order to verify user is logged in check DB

```
$user_decode_cookie = base64_decode($_COOKIE['cookiewithinfo']);

$cookie_implode = (explode('_', mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_decode_cookie)));

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='{$cookie_implode[0]}' AND session = '{$cookie_implode[1]}'")or die(mysql_error());
    $userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    return $userinfo;
```

step 4 - set COOKIE with username and uniqid

To verify it is correct user I get the COOKIE and make sure uniqid match with the username in the DB.

I was reading a bit on here and used the session as I saw was suggested.

I was using COOKIES in order to save login even after browser close.

Is this close in anyway to how it can be done somewhat safely or am I way out to lunch. Thanks as well for any input.

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` is now deprecated as of `PHP7` because of security issues. It is suggested that you switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: good catch, I always do now but this was just a copy and paste thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach looks reasonably secure.  The only thing I would change is to save `md5(PK . $uniqid)` instead of just the `$uniqid` in the cookie so that it would be almost impossible to brute force it, even with a botnet and years of attempts.

The `PK` would simply be any simple key that you'd keep private to your script.  You could keep the DB as it is and validate the secured session key in PHP after the query, or simply store the same secured key directly in the DB to keep your current query.

Note that you should use prepared statements on your arguments for security.

Comment: just out of curiosity is really the only way for this session to be taken over would be if someone was to hijack the actual cookie? Thanks for the reply to Ill throw in the encoding and random number for brute force attempts and thinking of adding limited login attempts.

Comment: If you use prepared statements as I suggested, the only way to hijacking it would be to guess the encoded id which would probably take centuries of processing to achieve.

Comment: Adding the encoding makes the visible id much bigger than the actual id you were already using.  Since its construction is not guessable since it relies on an invisible key and md5 hashing gives a fairly normal distributions, it is impossible to shorten the bruteforce process.

Comment: alright thats great info - and by prepared you mean using mysqli and escaping - Im only going to be accessing the DB once every page load to verify session id - Also just a side question would using session to check for current logged ok to use - IE ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) - more so it would only have to check for cookie once and could use session for the rest of the time? thanks

Comment: Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php for information on prepared statements.  Escaping is not the right solution anymore, and never was fully secure.

Comment: Ah i see prepared doesnt use the input as part of the sql statement anymore so no more injections - right on thanks